# Upload image cors [LinkedIn API]

Tags: api, next.js, linkedin-api

I can get the `uploadUrl` from **Linkedin api** from our server. However, when I use the uploadUrl inside axios or fetch it returns `CORS ERROR` and I don't know how to fix it.

Here's my messy code & cors error

[image]
[image]

Tried changing `POST` to `PUT` but no luck. I hope someone can help me.